# Recursion in scala. Trying to modify List in passed parameter(which is not possible obviously)

Tags: scala, recursion

In Java I had a method like this.

```
    public static void digPackageLines( List<PkgLine> pkgLineList, Tree treeParam ) {

    if ( findPkgLineTreeExist( treeParam ) == false ) {
        for ( Tree tree : findParents( treeParam ) ) {
            digPackageLines( pkgLineList, tree );
        }

    } else {

        for ( PkgLineTree pkgLineTree : findPkgLineTreeByTree( treeParam ) ) {
            pkgLineList.add( pkgLineTree.pkgLineId );

        }
    }
}
```

This would take a list and modify it by adding pkgLines to that list.  Now in scala this is not possible since all parameters are vals and cannot be modified.

This is what I have so far.

```
def digPackageLines(pkgLineList : Seq[ PkgLine ], tree_id : Long) : Unit = {

    if ( PkgLineTree.findPkgLineTreeExist(tree_id) == false ) {  //tree is parent if no lines found

        Tree.findParents(tree_id) map {
            tree =>
                digPackageLines(pkgLineList, tree.tree_id.get) //dig further into tree
        }

    } else { //found lines

        PkgLineTree.findByTreeId(tree_id) map {
            pkgLineTree =>
                PkgLine.findById(pkgLineTree.pkg_line_id).get //add this line to pkgLineList somehow
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm kind of stuck what to do.  I've been looking at tail recursion tutorials but they are pretty basic and just deal with numbers.  Do I need to return a list from the recursive function?  Functions can't have side effects so I'm guessing this is the only way.

My other main problem is adding objects to list.  Apparently I need to have a copy of the list and then append the object to it.  The problem is I can't create a new variable in the loop.  I'm sure there is a much easier way.  Thanks for any help.

## **EDIT**

At the very end I have done this.

```
val pkgLineList : Seq[ (PkgLine, Tree) ] = User.findUserJoinAllAcl(10) flatMap {
        user =>
            PkgLine.digPackageLines(Vector[ (PkgLine, Tree) ](), user._2.tree_id)
    }
```

Does this look correct.  I have modified the method to return a tuple.  Only difference though.  Seems to be working good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala you have mutable collections and immutable ones. The preference is to use immutable but you can always revert to mutable depending on the context.

Here, you want to append so using the immutable `List` is not ideal since the append operation takes O(n). Prepending is O(1). A typical way to resolve this is to use `List` and prepend and at the end use `reverse` to get the desired result.

You can use the mutable `ListBuffer` which can be converted to a list in a O(1) operation:

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

@annotation.tailrec // check that this is optimized for tail call
def digPackageLines(pkgLineList: ListBuffer[PkgLine], tree_id: Long): Unit = {

  if (PkgLineTree.findPkgLineTreeExist(tree_id) == false) {
    Tree.findParents(tree_id) map { tree =>
      digPackageLines(pkgLineList, tree.tree_id.get)
    }
  } else { //found lines and return result as List
    PkgLineTree.findByTreeId(tree_id) map { pkgLineTree =>
      pkgLineList += PkgLine.findById(pkgLineTree.pkg_line_id).get
    }
  }
}
```

But let's see how to do this in a more "functional" way. Let use an immutable `Vector` which has amortized O(1) append. The function will return the combined results, since the input cannot be mutated:

```
def digPackageLines(pkgLines: Vector[PkgLine], tree_id: Long): Vector[PkgLine] ={

  if (PkgLineTree.findPkgLineTreeExist(tree_id) == false) {
      val parentTrees = Tree.findParents(tree_id)
      parentTrees.foldLeft(pkgLines){ (lines, tree) =>
        digPackageLines(lines, tree.tree_id.get)
      }
    }
  } else { //found lines and return result as List
    val additions = PkgLineTree.findByTreeId(tree_id) map { pkgLineTree =>
      PkgLine.findById(pkgLineTree.pkg_line_id).get
    }
    pkgLines ++ additions
  }
}
```

same disclaimer as Submonoid applies *(N.b. I haven't run this, so there may be errors in it.)*

Comment: Nice, this worked out good.  I have a few questions though.  Why was Vector used, instead of say Seq? The append method is faster?  Why did you use a foldLeft method instead of map?  I have made an edit, that maybe you could look over right quick.

Comment: Seq is just a supertype of lots of collections - any 'sequence' type. So a Vector is in fact a Seq, as is a List. The default Seq() is a list, which as huynhjl points out will be slow if you're using append.

Comment: @DrewH, foldLeft appoximates best your imperative code. Say you found 2 parentTrees. In the imperative version you first process the first tree but then the result of the first recursive call is used as the input to the second recursive call (through the mutated java List). Using foldLeft preserve that semantic.

Comment: @DrewH, edit looks fine. If it compiles chances are it's good.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's default collections are immutable, which means you can't make changes to them. However, there are a separate package of mutable collections. The mutable variant of a `List` is a `ListBuffer`, which is available in the scala.collection.mutable package. Using a ListBuffer you would be able to do:

```
pkgLineList += PkgLine.findById(pkgLineTree.pkg_line_id).get
```

This would be a direct translation of your Java version. However, what you probably want to do is to rewrite it in a much more idiomatic Scala fashion. It looks like what you're doing is walking through some branching data structure and adding the results of things into a list. You can quite easily rewrite this in a primitive recursive fashion as so:

```
def digPackageLines(tree_id : Long) : Seq[PkgLine] = {
  def _digPackageLines(acc : List[PkgLine], tree_id : Long) : List[PkgLine] = {
    // Base case 
    if (PkgLineTree.findPkgLineTreeExist(tree_id)) {
      PkgLineTree.findByTreeId(tree_id) map {
        pkgLineTree =>
            PkgLine.findById(pkgLineTree.pkg_line_id).get
      } ::: acc
    } else {
      // We use flatMap instead of Map to concatenate the results of the recursive calls
      Tree.findParents(tree_id) flatMap { tree =>
        digPackageLines(pkgLineList, tree.tree_id.get)
      } ::: acc
    }
  }

  // Call our helper function with an empty list
  _digPackageLines(List[PkgLine](), tree_id)
}
```

(N.b. I haven't run this, so there may be errors in it.)

The key point to note is that we use an accumulator to store the results of our list as we go along. However, note that this isn't tail recursive, since we're branching at each stage and having to concatenate the results.